# Route to view_func with same decorators "flask"

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, decorator

lets suppose i have this routes:

```
app.add_url_rule('/',
                  view_func=index,
                  methods=['GET'])

app.add_url_rule('login',
                  view_func=login,
                  methods=['GET', 'POST'])

@validate_access()
def index():
    #......

@validate_access()
def login():
    #......
```

I have 2 endpoints with same decorator "@validate_access".
When i run this code i got

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:    wrapperAssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper
```

I don't know if its a bug or not. But please inform me if there is a solution for this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please add `@validate_access` decorator code. Look like it don't use `functools.wraps`. Or you can try set `endpoint` name explicitly: `app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index, methods=['GET'])` and `app.add_url_rule('/login', 'login', login, methods=['GET', 'POST'])`.

Comment: @tbicr I used `wraps` but still get problems in Flask 0.10. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352718/python-decroator-with-flask Can you take a look?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you dont provide `endpoint` to `add_url_rule` or `route`, the name of the method will be used as the endpoint. What's happening is the rule is being created with the name of your wrapping function, rather than the decorated function, probably because you arent using [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

```
from functools import wraps
def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        return f(*args, **kwds)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I used `wraps` but still get problems in Flask 0.10. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352718/python-decroator-with-flask Can you take a look?