# Python decorator with Flask

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I need to add a python decorator to Flask route functions, (basically I edited the code from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/98/))

```
def requires_admin(f):
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            #if not admin:
                #return render_template('error.html')
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

and use it like this will be OK:

```
@app.route('/admin/action')
@requires_admin
def AdminAction():
#NO error if NO parameter
```

But use it like this will have error:

```
@app.route('/admin/action/<int:id>')
@requires_admin
def AdminAction(id):
```

In Flask 0.10, I get errors like this (I just updated from Flask 0.9 to 0.10, and in Flask 0.9 there is no grammar error like this):

```
    @requires_admin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/flask/app.
py", line 1013, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/flask/app.
py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.6.egg/flask/app.
py", line 984, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint functi
on: wrapper
```

I am pretty new to the decorator stuff, how do I correct this error?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but possibly you need to provide an `endpoint` argument to the route? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540754/route-to-view-func-with-same-decorators-flask

Comment: @will-hart I just updated the question. Only with parameter there will be errors.

Comment: @JamesKing it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381560/most-effective-way-to-find-and-replace a nice question. You got downvotes only because of the lack of efforts. Get back with attempts and i'll ready to provide an answer.

Comment: @Avinash Raj Thank you for your attention. I solved that problem on my own. My question is actually how to edit files inline with Python. and The answer is `import fileinput`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two wrapper functions where you only need one. Notice that each wrapper function takes one argument. This should be a clue as to what is happening.

You have:

```
def decorator(take_a_function):
    def wrapper1(take_a_function):
        def wrapper2(*takes_multiple_arguments):
           # do stuff
           return take_a_function(*takes_multiple_arguments)

        return wrapper2
    return wrapper1
```

When you decorate a function with it:

```
@decorator
def my_function(*takes_multiple_arguments):
   pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def my_function(*takes_multiple_arguments):
   pass

my_function = decorator(my_function)
```

but doing `decorator(my_function)` returns `wrapper1`, which if you recall takes one
argument, `take_a_function`. This is clearly not what you want. You want `wrapper2` returned. As in your answer, the solution is to remove the outer wrapper(`wrapper1`):

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(takes_a_function):
    @wraps(takes_a_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # logic here
        return takes_a_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok I solved this problem by reading this answer [Route to view_func with same decorators "flask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540754/route-to-view-func-with-same-decorators-flask) given by @will-hart

I simply remove the `def wrapper(f)` and everything seems fine now. at leaset no grammar error.

```
from functools import wraps

def requires_admin(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        #if blah blah:
            #return blah blah
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Since I am pretty new to decorator and I dont know why. But hope this can help other ppl.

Comment: In general a decorator with no arguments besides the wrapped function requires just one inner function. In your first example `requires_admin` returns a function which in turn takes a second function. Two level decorators are for things like `@app.route(extra_args)` or `@wraps(f)`.