# How do you use Flask-Login and custom Python decorators to assign user permissions?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, flask-login

I cannot figure out how to get a Python decorator to work on a Flask view.

Here is my decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def admin_only(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("It did something")
        if current_user.is_anonymous:
            flash("Please log in to use this site.", "info")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        if not current_user.admin:
            abort(403)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@bp.errorhandler(403)
def forbidden_403(exception):
    return 'Admin access only', 403
```

And here is my view:

```
@bp.route('/add_info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@admin_only
def add_info():
    add_info_form = AddInfoForm()
    if add_info_form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Code here")
    else:
        for error in add_info_form.errors:
            flash(error, "info")
    context = {
        'add_info_form': add_info_form,
    }
    return render_template('admin/add_info.html', **context)
```

The decorator simply doesn't function--the view works but lets any user through. None of the code that should be implemented before the view function runs gets run. I've tried various different formatting tricks, but nothing has worked.

I've used the code from this answer - [Python decorator with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352718/python-decorator-with-flask):

```
def decorator(take_a_function):
    def wrapper1(take_a_function):
        def wrapper2(*takes_multiple_arguments):
           # do stuff
           return take_a_function(*takes_multiple_arguments)

        return wrapper2
    return wrapper1
```

Nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure why this works, but I will say this:

I'm using a blueprint file structure that's something like this:

```
/app
   /user
      /__init__.py
      /forms.py
      /templates/user
         /user.html
   /lists
      /__init__.py
      /forms.py
      /templates/lists
         /lists.html
   /admin
      /__init__.py
      /forms.py
      /templates/admin
         /add_user.html
         /add_info.html
         /all_lists.html
   __init__.py
   forms.py
   models.py
   /templates
      index.html
```

I had previously been defining the decorator function in `/admin/__init__.py`. When I simply moved it to the `app/__init__.py` file, the function works fine!

I'm happy, but I'm also hoping someone can contribute some details on why this happens this way. If not, I'll accept my answer. Maybe it has something to do with the order Flask runs functions in an `__init__.py` file...

Comment: I suspect it didn't work when you had the decorator function in `admin/__init__.py` because you weren't importing it correctly to your `routes.py` module. Did you have `from app import admin_only` in your `routes.py` instead of `from app.admin import admin_only`?